# sql query for filtering data with where multiple criteria on same column of table

Tags: mysql

I have following Sample table.
table having combination of name and key column unique records

```
ID   name      key          key_type 
-----------------------------------
118  ab         12          aw1 
119  fb         13          1Y2 
120  cb         14          qw3 
121  ab         15          4123
122  cs         12          23d2

select * from Sample where name ='ab' and key= '12' 

select * from Sample where name ='fb' and key= '13'
```

how to write single query for both record ?

Comment: so whats the problem with the query you are trying?

Comment: `WHERE (a AND b) OR (c AND d)` should do the trick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest way would be `union all`

```
select * from Sample where name ='ab' and key= '12' 
union all
select * from Sample where name ='fb' and key= '13'
```

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way would be

```
select * 
  from Sample 
  where (name = 'ab' and `key` = '12') 
    or (name = 'fb' and `key` = '13')
```

Demo here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3eabc/3

Throw an index on (name, `key`) for good measure.

```
create index name_key on sample(name, `key`);
```